# Sizing a motor for cake turntable

Tags: dc-motor, rpm

I have to build an automatic (self-revolving) cake turntable to rotate a maximum of 15 pounds and I'm not entirely sure as to how to size  the motor to be used (in terms of maximum current or voltage ratings) or what type of motor to use.

I'm aware of speed control methods for motors and how to drive them but I don't know how to choose them. Can I simply use any DC motor and vary the voltage in order to keep the RPM up based on the load (weight of cake)?

Comment: Look up "synchronous motor" for the type. That is what I usually find on such devices. If you need to slow or speed it up, use a belt and pulleys or else a gearing system or else a roller on a circular track at some radii or any of several other basic concepts like that. (Unless you MUST use DC. But you didn't say you had to.) You will have to deal with imbalanced loads. But most of the weight is vertically supported by the structure, so the motor only has to deal with a relatively modest load in most cases.

Comment: @jonk No I don't have to use a DC motor so a synchronous motor is fine. How would I cater for an imbalanced load ?

Comment: Flat surface riding on ball bearings in a race? There are lots them. Look up "lazy Susan" and see what comes up. Something like that to start. Add motor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the speed of a DC motor over a wide range. But it is difficult if you want to run it slowly and still have a decent torque.

In your case it is much easier to to start with a DC geared motor which already runs close to the speed you need. (But faster of course) The gearing will also make that you can use a much smaller motor, which uses less power and less noise.

Look for something like "dc motor X RPM" with X being 5, 10 or 20, whatever you need. If your motor uses gear or belt to drive the turntable take that into account when choosing the RPM.

Comment: I would add that amazon has many of these available. Something like this should work well: https://smile.amazon.com/15RPM-Shaft-Torque-Turbine-Geared/dp/B00EDMIH7E/

As for choosing the motor size, for applications like this honestly it's easiest to just guess/overbuild it. For you, I would guess a motor over 2" in diameter is probably the edge of too big, and 1" in diameter is the edge of too small.

Comment: if the turntable has good bearings a 1" motor is likely sufficient. the motor doen't need to lift the cake only spin it.  but if the cake is to contain strippers a larger motor may be needed.